# Do braided stainless steel hoses with surface corrosion require replacement?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture, hose

I'd be grateful if someone would resolve some conflicting advice I've been given on this topic.

Some argue that the braiding does not contribute to the pressure rating of these hoses, and that surface corrosion does not indicate urgent replacement.

On the other hand, online sources such as [this](https://metalhoseonline.com/common-causes-of-hose-failures/) (in addition to [this study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225930697_Failure_of_a_braided_stainless_steel_hose_connector)) imply the contrary, that corrosion is among the causes of braided hose failure.

What would you say is correct? Would extensive corrosion require urgent replacement?

Comment: How old are the hoses?

Comment: There are some that are quite old (20 years old) that I would replace anyway. I was thinking what should be done with new hoses less than 5 years old that have superficial rust.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of corrosion, some may be more surface finish failure and the hose can last for many years if not a decade. I have seen rusty lines that have some of the strands breaking and the line was not leaking not yet, I would suggest once the outer braid starts failing it is time to replace the line.  the urgency would be based on several factors like is the line disturbed or bumped my wife has a buck she stores under the sink that bumps the line in that case it may need to be replaced sooner than one that is never touched.  The pressure is also a factor, if you have less than 60 psi I would not be as concerned compared to a home with 90 psi. The last is personal opinion, some want to replace for any reason others may wait for a drip and each opinion is probably based on past experience and disposable income.

Answer (score 1):

The first of your links is about METAL hose used in industrial applications, not the kind of SS braided hose that you use in houses. The residential use hoses are plastic hoses that have the metal braiding as a protection from external physical damage, ie rodents chewing on it, sharp objects cutting it, etc. The plastic hose inside is not necessarily reinforced with fibers like the ones without the SS braiding, so if the braiding corrodes ***and is gone***, you increase the risk of the plastic hose "blowing out" if there is a pressure spike. But at the same time, the risk of a pressure spike in modern homes is very very low. I wouldn't get overly concerned about it.

The second link goes to an article that needs to be downloaded, but from the synopsis they seem to be discussing the risks of the CONNECTORS deteriorating.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your hoses are in a garage where the cost of a leak is zero, replace the hoses. The cost of new hoses is very low compared to the potential damage.